# How to use PreparedStatement and Case INsensitive search

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, case-insensitive

**1.How do I use PrepareStatement for familyname and givenname?

2.Also, how do I case insensitive search by familyname or givenname?**

```
String query ="SELECT agent.familyname, agent.givenname" +
                    " FROM agent" +
                    " WHERE agent.agentid = piececreation.agentid" +
                    " AND (LOWER(familyname) = '"+agent_lastname+"' OR LOWER(givenname) = '"+agent_name+"') ORDER by familyname";


            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pst.setString(1, agent_lastname);
            pst.setString(2, agent_name);
            // Executing the insert
            pst.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make familyName or givenName to lowercase too since you are already using LOWER DB API

```
String query ="SELECT agent.familyname, agent.givenname" +
                        " FROM agent" +
                        " WHERE agent.agentid = piececreation.agentid" +
                        " AND (LOWER(familyname) = '"+agent_lastname.toLowerCase()+"' OR LOWER(givenname) = '"+agent_name.toLowerCase()+"') ORDER by familyname";
```

When you are using `PreparedStatement` dont append values directly in your SQL, if you do that you are prone to [SQL Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) instead parametrize your values.

```
String query = 
                "SELECT agent.familyname, agent.givenname"
                + " FROM agent"
                + " WHERE agent.agentid = ?"
                + " AND (" 
                + " LOWER(familyname) = ? OR LOWER(givenname) = ?" 
                + ") " 
                + " ORDER by familyname";


        pst.setInt(1, piececreation.agentid);
        pst.setString(2, agent_lastname.toLowerCase());
        pst.setString(3, agent_name.toLowerCase());
```

Then set values calling appropriate setXXX methods as defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

You can read tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Cool, thanks mate! But I heard that "+name+" is vulnerable to SQL injections. So how do I use PreparedStatement here? any ideas?

Comment: PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   
   pst.setString(1, agent_lastname.toLowerCase());
   pst.setString(2, agent_name.toLowerCase());
   // Executing the insert
   pst.executeUpdate();
  
   
  
   
   
   System.out.println("query" + query); // console message
   Statement st = conn.createStatement(); // connection statement
   ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query); // executing our query

Comment: You also need to set agent id

Comment: everything from WHERE? lets say I use AND

Comment: and if piececreation.agentid is an Integer?

Comment: you have setInt, setFloat and many other setXXX available... edited my answer

Comment: but it is not given in the java itself..its direct data from the sql. so it shows error when I do setInt..and when I do setString it shows error integer = character varying

Comment: in that case you can remove that and just use your old code for agent id, you should parameterize values which are coming from java, ui etc

Comment: Error: **A result was returned when none was expected.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query for caseinsensetive search.

```
String query = 
                "SELECT agent.familyname, agent.givenname"
                + " FROM agent"
                + " WHERE agent.agentid = ?"
                + " AND (" 
                + " familyname ilike ? OR givenname ilike ?" 
                + ") " 
                + " ORDER by familyname";


        pst.setInt(1, piececreation.agentid);
        pst.setString(2, agent_lastname.toLowerCase());
        pst.setString(3, agent_name.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: You can user `ilike` for case insensetive search of the varchar values