# How to write query in database to make search case insenstive and display multiple records based on search

Tags: java, sql, database

My SQL query

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Application where name like '"+ name+"%'");
```

Could you please suggest me how to make it case insensitive and based on search it should display multiple records which starts with search keyword since I have used 'like'.

Suppose when I search by 'C' in search button. When submit it should display Car, cat etc. (in my database) in the jsp page, but it is returning only one record.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326952/how-to-use-preparedstatement-and-case-insensitive-search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate show real SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql)

Comment: For the `it is returning only one record` part: [`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--) returns a [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Application where LOWER(name) like '"+ name..toLowerCase() +"%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You did the correct thing by trying to use a prepared statement.  However, you then decided not to actually use the statement and instead use a SQL injection-prone `WHERE` clause.  Something along these lines should solve your problem:

```
String sql = "select * from Application where LOWER(name) like ?");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" + name.toLowerCase() + "%");
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

However, it is not ideal from a performance point of view to be lowercasing every record in a single query.  If you plan to support case insensitive searches by name often, you might want to consider storing the lowercase version of the name in the `Application` table.  This should speed up the query.

Comment: Thank you . It works. I have two records that starts with 'CI ', but it is dispalying one record when i search by CI keyword

Comment: Please help me in this

Comment: The query should be returning both records, but you may be handling the result set incorrectly.  Please include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    DBConnection db=new DBConnection();
    HttpSession hs = request.getSession();
    String name=request.getParameter("appname");
    List<Details> dbean=db.getAllDetails(name);

    hs.setAttribute("detbean",dbean);
    if(dbean.isEmpty())
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<caption>Sorry, No Record Found</caption>");
    }
    else
    response.sendRedirect("Application.jsp");
}
```

my jsp code

```
               <TABLE BORDER="1" >
                <TR>
                    <TH> <h4 >Application Name</h4> </TH>
                     <TH> <h4 >Abbrebation</h4> </TH>
                      <TH> <h4 >Primary Contact Name</h4> </TH>
                      <TH> <h4 >Primary Contact Number</h4> </TH>
                      <TH> <h4 >Seconday Contact Name</h4> </TH>
                      <TH> <h4 >Secondary Contact Number</h4> </TH>
                      </TR>
```

Collection dbean = (ArrayList)request.getSession().getAttribute("detbean");
       Iterator i=dbean.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            beanclasses.Details item= (beanclasses.Details)i.next();
        
             <%=item.getAPPLICATIONNAME()%>
              <%=item.getAPPABBR()%>
              <%=item.getPRIMARYPERSON()%>
              <%=item.getPRICONTACT()%>
              <%=item.getSECONDAEYPERSON() %>
              <%=item.getSECCONTACT() %>

Comment: in another jsp , i am passing the "appname" keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
ps.execute();
System.out.println("Entering in to the fucntion 13");
ResultSet rs  =ps.getResultSet();
if(rs.next())
{
System.out.println("Entering in to the fucntion 4");
Details dbean=new Details();
dbean.setAPPLICATION_ID(rs.getInt(1));
dbean.setAPPLICATIONNAME(rs.getString(2));
dbean.setAPPABBR(rs.getString(3));
dbean.setPRIMARYPERSON(rs.getString(4));
dbean.setPRICONTACT(rs.getInt(5));
dbean.setSECONDAEYPERSON(rs.getString(6));
dbean.setSECCONTACT(rs.getInt(7));

de.add(dbean);
System.out.println("Entering in to the fucntion 1" + de);
}
}
catch(SQLException e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return de;
```

Comment: Now this is getting ridiculous.  You should have pasted this code in your _question_, not as an answer.  Arguably, you should have closed your current question and asked a new one.

Answer (score 0):

On databases that support it, you can use `ilike` in place of `like` for a case-insensitive search.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Application where name ilike '"+ name+"%'");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not just dump code as answers, also provide an explanation of why it solves the problem.